# Out of close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, vote-to-close

When do I get them back? It simply says "You have no more close votes today." I would prefer it say "You have no more close votes today, please try again in X hours" similar to when you're out of votes.

Comment: Never. Close votes are running low these days, so they've been forced to ration a fixed amount to people. When you run out, that's it! Too bad you used all yours. :(

Comment: "6 to 8 weeks" would just be brutal :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree, this should behave the same way as the normal voting `<div>`.

So when you reach the limit, it'll now tell you how many hours until 00:00 UTC when you get more. Just like upvotes/downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Same time everything else gets reset on SO - 12 AM, UTC, which is in about 50 minutes from now.

If they implemented this feature then it would also have to apply to upvotes/downvotes, comment votes, rep caps, etc.  Perhaps an entry in the FAQ would suffice.

Comment: @Josh K: Not sure which epoch you're referring to but the Unix epoch is also 00:00.

Comment: It was a joke... kinda. Badly played because they both at are 00:00.